# NuGet missing assembly for NLog

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I've recently started using NuGet in VS2015, and I have come across the problem where when trying to use 'NLog' I am getting a missing assembly error in my project.

I have previously used NLog via NuGet in another projects with no problem but this time it is not working.

In my using statements
[image: Missing assembly]

NuGet package manager;
[image: NuGet]

NLog correctly appears in my references

[image: References]

As you can see, I'm also using other packages such as Oracle data access, and this works fine with no issue, it is just NLog where it does not work.

Now I have tried to;
Uninstall and re-install of NLog package (with shutdown of VS inbetween, and cleaning solution, and even reboot of machine) - multiple times
Uninand re-install of NuGet packagae manager (with shutdown of VS inbetween, and cleaning solution)

I have looked in the following files, but can't see any differences compared to last use of NLog in another project which was successful.

- App.Config
- my project.csproj
- packages.config

And NLog does appear in the \packages folder

Any ideas what the issue could be and what I need to do to fix the error?

Comment: Yes I did change the framework version, but I have reinstalled NLog package since them (multiple times).  I think I even installed NLog for the first time after this change.  I even just tried this again, and no luck.

Comment: It seems I replied to a comment which has since disappeared!  For reference the comment asked if I had changed Framework version, and if so to reinstall the package

Comment: It was me deleted my comment after reading you reinstalled Nlog. I suggest you to remove nlog package, close visual studio, clear all related files (in package folder,remove packages.config file entries if any exist, etc) then restart VS and try again. Also can you tell what changes you made. I mean from which version to which version? Did you changed project type etc?

Comment: No that didn't work.  I removed all my packages.  Closed VS, Checked that the folder, and the packages.config were deleted (they were). checked that there were no reference to the packages in .csproj and app.config (there wasn't), restarted VS, resinstalled my packages.  And I have the same problem.  The other packages are OK, but NLOG does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that after spending hours on this over 2 days I finally managed to resolve the issue myself within a few minutes of posting on here!

The problem was confounded by the fact that I had one solution with 2 projects.

Project 1 didn't have NLog installed 
Project 2 did have NLog installed

I thought that NLog was only being used from Project 2, and hence why the package was only installed here.  But Project 2 had a dependency on project 1 and it turns out that it was through this dependency that NLog was also used in project 1.  As it was a static reference then it didn't help me to track it down.

So I had to install NLog for both projects.  Once I done this, then the issue went away.

Thanks anyway to all your help

Comment: That what I said. see my answer ! 2)`Install-Package NLog` : Be sure you install the NuGet on the project you are working on

Comment: Yes, although I realised this just before you posted (or at least before I read your post).  But I voted you up anyway.  It is very unusual for me to have a solution with more than one project.

Comment: it's Ok for me  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Shell , you must Open the solution :

```
1)`Uninstall-Package NLog` :  Don't forget to delete Obj Folders manually
2)`Install-Package NLog` : Be sure you install the NuGet on the project you are working on
```

Comment: I tried this and it makes no difference to using the package manager.  I still have the same problem.

Comment: Don't forget to delete Obj Folders manualy (even Bin in case).